# Is it possible to access the Salesforce Performance Test as a Customer Community user?

Tags: javascript, community, customer-community, performance

There are a number of users who only have access to our community that are experiencing a lot of issues with slow pages and I want to gauge where the performance problems are coming from (e.g. latency, RAM, browser etc.).

Is it possible to run the Salesforce Performance Test (typically accessed by adding *speedtest.jsp* to the end of your Salesforce domain) as a Customer Community user and, if so, how would such a user access it?

Comment: Have you logged into the community as a community user and tried adding it to the URL as per the usual method?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't include that in my post. I did try appending speedtest.jsp to the root Community URL and got an "Invalid Page" message.

Comment: IMO using an outside, non-SF performance testing tool will give you a higher quality signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out, the answer is **yes** provided you append *speedtest.jsp* to the host of the URL and *not* at the community level path:

- mydomain.force.com/s/my-community/speedtest.jsp ❌
- mydomain.force.com/s/speedtest.jsp ❌
- mydomain.force.com/speedtest.jsp ✅